# I want to validate if there is any garbage value in the form of special signs in a column of the table

Tags: database, databricks, etl, azure-synapse

I want to validate if there is any garbage value in the form of special signs in a column of the table. Can you plz help?

select * from mytable
where regexp_like(column_name,'[^[:alnum:]]');

select * from mytable
where length(translate(column_name, '¿ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', '¿')) > 0;

Answer (score 0):

To validate the presence of garbage values in the form of special characters in a column of a table using both regular expressions and the translation approach.

I have tried the below approach in pyspark.

To validate if there are any special characters in a column of a Spark DataFrame.

**Using regex:** The `RLIKE` operator is used to check if the column contains any characters that are not alphanumeric.
The regex pattern **[^a-zA-Z0-9]** matches any character that is not an uppercase or lowercase letter or a digit.
The  `WHERE`  clause is used to filter out the rows that contain special characters.

**Using translate:** The **`REGEXP_REPLACE`** function is used to replace all alphanumeric characters in the column with an empty string.
The `LENGTH` function is then used to check if the resulting string has a length greater than 0, which indicates that the column contains special characters.
The `WHERE` clause is used to filter out the rows that contain special characters.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SpecialCharValidation").getOrCreate()
data = [("John123",),
        ("Mary#456",),
        ("Bob",),
        ("Alice_789",)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["column_name"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
result_regex = spark.sql("""
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE column_name RLIKE '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
""")
result_translate = spark.sql("""
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable
    WHERE LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '[a-zA-Z0-9]', '')) > 0
""")
result_regex.show()
result_translate.show()
```

[image]